# For each loop string

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm getting a file content from my website:

```
    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
    Dim text = client.DownloadString("http://myurl.com/raw.php")
```

The `text` is following:

```
Line
Another Line
Test1
Test2
```

Now, how can I run a loop through the `text` variable, to have a text from each line ?

I have tried this:

```
    Dim str As String() = text.Split(":::")
    For Each line As String In str
        MsgBox(line)
    Next
```

And I was finishing each line with the `:::`, but this method seems ugly and I hope there are better solutions?

Comment: Have you thought of returning an XML string rather than plain text?

Comment: @bendataclear Well, I am not against such solution. :)

Comment: `text` is not a `Dim` but a variable. `Dim` is the statement used to declare local variables and class members.

Comment: XML might be a good solution but it depends on exactly what data you're returning via the php file.

Comment: @bendataclear Just the string, containg the article news.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of the vb.net side if useing XML:

```
Dim doc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
doc.Load("http://myurl.com/raw.php")

Dim list = doc.GetElementsByTagName("article")

For Each item As System.Xml.XmlElement In list
    MsgBox(item.InnerText)
Next
```

Edit:

Example XML schema:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!-- File generated at 22/11/2012 17:22 -->
<articleList>
  <article>Hello</article>
  <article>World</article>
  <article>Fish</article>
</articleList>
```

Another advantage of switching to XML now will mean it will be easier to add more details in the future (like article header, date/time, auther etc).

Comment: Could you post the XML schema, that PHP should return? Something like... `<xml><article>Hello</article><article>World</article></xml>` ?

Comment: Also, how can I display (and get them inside of the loop) additional data such as date or article author as you said?

Comment: Great place to start is here: http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/XML-Programming-VB.NET.aspx

Comment: Yea, nevermind I have fixed all my questions/problems on my own :).

Answer (score 6):

```
Dim lines As String() = text.Split(Environment.NewLine)
For Each line As String In lines
    MsgBox(line)
Next
```

This maybe doesn't work because the *newline* character in the original string is different from `Environment.Newline`. This can happen if the string comes from a Unix-based source.

An alternative approach could be:

```
Dim reader = new StringReader(text)
While True
    Dim line = reader.ReadLine()
    If line is Nothing
        Exit While
    Else
        MsgBox(line)
    End If
End While
```

Comment: You may want to change `text.Split(Environment.NewLine)` to `text.Split(CChar(Environment.NewLine))` the former gives me an error of course I have Option Strict On

Comment: I dont know why, but it doesn't really works for me since for the `Hello<newline>World` (`<newline>` is just a new line in the text, as the comments here doesn't allow to place new lines) it does return just one MsgBox containing `Hello<newline>World` instead of two MsgBoxe's - one with `Hello` and second `World`. Hope you understand it.

Comment: @Scott are you saying that you have an XML Style document that you are parsing, with <newline> being your delineator?

Comment: @MarkHall No, I said that `<newline>` is just a "sign" that new line is placed there, since I can not place new line here, in comments. I mean this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Q4v8bHrH

Comment: @Scott I posted an alternative approach

Comment: @Scott: Maybe the lines are split by line feeds instead of carriage returns (see my next comment). I suggest that you try `Dim lines As String() = text.Split(new String() {vbCr, vbLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`. That should cover all cases.

Comment: @MarkHall: Since `Environment.NewLine` returns the two-character sequence CRLF on Windows systems, `CChar(Environment.NewLine)` returns just `CR`, the first character. If the source of the data is from a unix system, it is likely separated by LFs.

Comment: @Heinzi: You should add that as an answer.

Comment: Looks like OP opted for an answer that has nothing to do with the question at all. But thanks for the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Using `text.Split(CChar(Environment.NewLine))`, as suggested in another answer, is not optimal: `Environment.NewLine` returns the two-character sequence `CR LF` on Windows systems. Thus, `CChar(Environment.NewLine)` returns just `CR`, the first character of the string. If the source of the data is from a unix system, it is likely separated by `LF`s.

If you are unsure about the exact line endings, you could use the following:

```
Dim lines As String() = text.Split(new String() {vbCrLf, vbCr, vbLf}, 
                                   StringSplitOptions.None)
```

That should cover all cases, since it splits on `CR` alone, on `LF` alone and on a combination of both.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to bring this up years later... I just found a easier way to do it:

```
dim lin() as string
lin() = TextBox1.Text.Split(vbCrLf)
```