# read from an encrypted file into strings

Tags: vb.net, encryption, aes

i have a custom settings file in plain text, the file is read and then each line represents variable setting. Below is what the file contains

online
19X.13X.XX.1XX
location
spec
col
storage path

I can encrypt the file and put it on the users machines, i don't want them to make any changes to this or read what is on the file

i can decrypt the file back onto the disc, but i don't want that, what i need is to use the values only in memory.

here is what i have to write back the decrypted file (something i found online )

```
    Public Function Decrypt(ByVal B() As Byte, ByVal PSW As String) As Byte()

    ' generates a key from the password
    Dim pdb As System.Security.Cryptography.PasswordDeriveBytes = New System.Security.Cryptography.PasswordDeriveBytes(PSW, New Byte() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10})

    ' this holds the encrypted 
    Dim ms As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream()

    ' this object holds the information about the AES encryption
    Dim AESE As System.Security.Cryptography.Aes = New System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged()
    AESE.Key = pdb.GetBytes(AESE.KeySize / 8)
    AESE.IV = pdb.GetBytes(AESE.BlockSize / 8)

    ' decrypt the data
    Dim cs As System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream = New System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(ms, AESE.CreateDecryptor(), System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    cs.Write(B, 0, B.Length)
    cs.Close()
    Return ms.ToArray()
End Function
```

i need help to read each line and assign it to the variables.
Thank-you in advance

Comment: You might want to have a look at [**How to: Convert an Array of Bytes into a String in Visual Basic**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/how-to-convert-an-array-of-bytes-into-a-string) and also [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13517056/3740093).

Comment: No luck , tried a few ideas but still does not convert to A STRING...

Comment: My first link literally shows you how to convert a `Byte()` into a `String`. It includes a complete code example. How could you not get that working? It is just `Dim s As String = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(<your byte array here>)`.

Comment: Hi Vincent, i got the sting back but the strings still had some encoding, i think my issue s that i have not been able to figure out what type of encoding. The stings still had some garage...

Comment: figured out that there was no encoding, was default, the solution was Dim string Val=system.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(Byte)

Comment: That's still an encoding: ANSI. Though it shouldn't really matter... Anyway, glad you got it working!